# Server initiated server-client websocket messages in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a node js app that receives data from a sensor device via POST requests. It also serves frontend to monitor that data. I want it to send data updates via websocket to all connected clients

Here's what I came up with:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
const ws = expressWs.getWss('/ws');

function sendAll(data) {
  ws.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    client.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}

setInterval(async () => {
  try {
    let message = { message: 'dataUpdated', data: { foo: 'bar } };
    sendAll(message);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}, 1000 * 5);

app.use(express.static('./static/'));
// tell the app to parse HTTP body messages
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// routes
const apiRoutes = require('./api/routes/api-routes');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

I can use the `sendAll` function to broadcast data. But I'd like to be able to also use this function inside `apiRoutes` where I process the incoming requests from the sensor. How can I pass it there, or maybe get access to the `expressWs` instance and create same function in the included `api-routes` file?

Comment: Okay, that was a stupid question =) I just exported the sendAll function and imported it in the other file where I wanted to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple =)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
const ws = expressWs.getWss('/ws');

export function wsBroadcast(data) {
  ws.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    client.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}

app.use(express.static('./static/'));
// tell the app to parse HTTP body messages
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// routes
const apiRoutes = require('./api/routes/api-routes');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

And then just import it in the file that needs it to broadcast messages:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { wsBroadcast } from '../server';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/data', (req, res) => {
  wsBroadcast({ message: 'gotData', data: req.body });
  ...
```